# merge boolean variable works on output, not in input in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, merge-field

I have a collection `List<boolean>` and I want to display this list on VF page.

But the issue is , merege variable is working fine in `<apex:outputText>`, not in `<apex:inputCheckBox>`.So my page isn't getting saved.

**ApexClass:**

```
public class TestController {

    public List<boolean> boolList {get; set;}

    public TestController () {
        boolList = new List<boolean>{true, false, true};
    }
}
```

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="TestController">
    <apex:form >
     <table> 
    <tr>
      <apex:repeat value="{!boolList}" var="entry">
        <td>
           <apex:outputText value="{!entry}"/>
           <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!entry}"/>  <!-- Here I am getting unknown Prperty issue-->                              
        </td>
      </apex:repeat>  
    </tr>
</table>  
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

I know, to use any variable in `<apex:inputTextBox>`, variable has to be merge variable. `{get; set;}`. But we have declared `boolList` as getter and setter. and we are iterating over that boolist in `<apex:repeat>`.

any idea?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is your purpose for a list of booleans?

Answer (score 2):

Look at the docs:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputCheckbox.htm

the attribute type for value is object, you are passing boolean instead of an object

> **value** ***Object***    A merge field that references the controller class
>   variable that is associated with this checkbox. For example, if the
>   name of the associated variable in the controller class is myCheckbox,
>   use value="{!myCheckbox}" to reference the variable.      10.0    global

Create a wrapper class and modify your code as pasted below:

```
<apex:page controller="TestController">
    <apex:form >
     <table> 
    <tr>
      <apex:repeat value="{!boolwrap}" var="entry">
        <td>
           <apex:outputText value="{!entry.boolval}"/>
           <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!entry.boolval}"/>  <!-- Here I am getting unknown Prperty issue-->                              
        </td>
      </apex:repeat>  
    </tr>
</table>  
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

public with sharing class TestController {

```
    public List<boolean> boolList {get; set;}

    public List<booleanclass> boolwrap {get;set;}
    public Map<String, List<Product2>> myMap {get; set;}

    public TestController() {
    boolwrap  = new List<booleanclass>();
    boolList = new List<boolean>{true,false,true};
        for(boolean b: boollist){
            boolwrap.add(new booleanclass(b));
        }
    }

    public class booleanclass{
    public boolean boolval{get;set;}

    public booleanclass(boolean bool){
    boolval = bool;
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `value` attribute must reference a field that has a `get` and `set` method i.e. an [Apex property](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm).

Here is one way to accomplish that for your case:

```
public class TestController {

    public class BooleanAdapter {
        public Boolean value {get; set;}
        BooleanAdapter(Boolean value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public List<BooleanAdapter> boolList {get; set;}

    public TestController () {
        boolList = new List<BooleanAdapter>{
                new BooleanAdapter(true),
                new BooleanAdapter(false),
                new BooleanAdapter(true)
                };
    }
}
```

with this Visualforce:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!boolList}" var="entry">
  <td>
     <apex:outputText value="{!entry.value}"/>
     <apex:inputCheckBox value="{!entry.value}"/>
  </td>
</apex:repeat>
```